# How to read the IntelliSense to use LINQ effectively

Tags: c#, linq

I am new to C# LINQ. This is a general basic question on how to use IntelliSense to use LINQ effectively. I am working on a small piece of code to find the average file size in a folder. The following lines are part of the code.

```
string[] dirfiles = Directory.GetFiles("c:\\orderprocessing\\");
var avg = dirfiles.Select(file => new FileInfo(file).Length).Average();
```

This code works fine and I got it from a website. If I have to write it by myself, I am wondering how to find out what to pass to the Select() method. When I hover over it, the IntelliSense shows the following:

```
IEnumerable<TResult> IEnumerable<string, TResult>(Func<string, TResult> 
selector) (+ 1 overload)
```

I want to know how to read this suggestion and come up with file => new FileInfo(file).Length to pass to the method? Sorry if the question is very basic!

Comment: do you know Func<>?, it is a `Func<ItemType, bool>` by ItemType as dirfiles is a `IEnumerable<string>` it will be `Func<string, bool>`. if it was `IEnumerable<SomeClass>` it would have been `Func<SomeClass, bool>`

Comment: Probably it's Func<string, int>?

Comment: Yes, in select TResult is of your output type, (in this case int or long), in Where, First, FirstOrDefault, .... TResult is always bool (which determines if each object matches your condition or not)

Comment: you can even do it like this:  `Func<string, int> GetLength = (file) => new FileInfo(file).Length;` and then: `var avg = dirfiles.Select(GetLength).Average();`

Comment: I think the above example makes it more clear.

Comment: Yes, it is. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An expression like

```
x => expression using x
```

or

```
(x, y, ...) => expression using x, y, ...
```

Is called a Lambda expression. It is a very concise way of writing a method to be used as a delegate right where you need it. You can think of a delegate as a function pointer that you can pass as parameter to another method.

The two expressions from above translate to

```
resultType HiddenMethodName(parameterType x)
{
    return expression using x;
}
```

or

```
resultType HiddenMethodName(parameterType1 x, parameterType2 y, ...)
{
    return expression using x, y, ...;
}
```

The point is that the types are inferred by the C# compiler. E.g. you only write `file => ...` and C# knows that `file` is an input parameter of type `string`, since you called `Select` on an array of `string`.

```
Func<string, TResult> selector
```

means that you must pass it a function with a string input parameter. The result type is the generic type `TResult`.

The Intellisense information ...

```
IEnumerable<TResult> IEnumerable<string>.Select<string, TResult>(
    Func<string, TResult> selector)
```

... has the structure ...

```
ReturnType InputType.ExtensionMethod<InputElementType, ResultElementType>(
    function delegate that transforms input to output)
```

... and means that we have an `Enumerable<string>`: the array `string[] dirfiles`. On this input enumeration we apply the extension method `Select` (after the dot).

`Select<string, TResult>` expects an input enumeration of type `IEnumerable<string>` and returns an output enumeration of type `IEnumerable<TResult>` (this is the return type you see at the beginning). The type `TResult` is unknown at this stage, as it depends on what your lambda expression returns.

The point of this `Select` extension method is to convert an input enumeration to an output enumeration (possibly) of another type. The transformation of each element of the input enumeration is performed by the delegate `Func<string, TResult> selector` (given as lambda expression).

Your lambda expression `file => new FileInfo(file).Length` has a string input parameter `file` and returns a result of type `long` (the file length given as a 64 bit integer). `.Average()` transforms the resulting `IEnumerable<long>` to a `double`.

In addition to the links provided by @BasilKosovan, you might also have a look at [Generics (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/) (that's the thing with the angle brackets `<>`).

Answer (score 1):

At first, you maybe want to know how VS knows what to show you. There is XML doc(see [Documenting your code with XML comments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/codedoc)).
In c#, we have delegates(see [Func<T,TResult> Delegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-2?view=netframework-4.8)). It's a way how to pass a method as an argument. Let's consider your parameter:

```
file => new FileInfo(file).Length
```

It's called [Lambda expressions (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions)

And it unfolds as a method(it's called *Anonymous Method*):

```
int someMethod(string fileName) {
 return new FileInfo(file).Length;
}
```